# php array conversion for json string conversion

Tags: php, json

I have the following PHP array

```
Array ( 
         [subjecttable] => Array ( 
                            [0] => Array ( 
                                     [subject] => maths 
                                     [svalue] => 1 
                            ) 
                            [1] => Array ( 
                                     [subject] => english 
                                     [svalue] => 2 
                            ) 
                            [2] => Array ( 
                                     [subject] => physics 
                                     [svalue] => 3 
                            ) 
         ) 
         [Monthtable] => Array ( 
                            [0] => Array ( 
                                     [month] => Jan 
                                     [mvalue] => 1 
                            ) 
                            [1] => Array ( 
                                     [month] => Feb 
                                     [mvalue] => 2 
                            ) 
                            [2] => Array ( 
                                     [month] => Mar 
                                     [mvalue] => 3 
                            ) 
            ) 
)
```

I converted this from the json string given below

```
{"subjecttable": [ {"subject":"maths","svalue":"1"}, {"subject":"english","svalue":"2"}, {"subject":"physics","svalue":"3"} ], "Monthtable": [ {"month":"Jan","mvalue":"1"}, {"month":"Feb","mvalue":"2"}, {"month":"Mar","mvalue":"3"} ] }
```

I want to convert the above php array to

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
            [subjecttable] => subject 
            [monthtable] => month 
            [month] => jan 
            [subject] => maths 
            [svalue] => 1 
            [mvalue] => 1 
  ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
            [subjecttable] => svalue 
            [monthtable] => mvalue 
            [month] => feb 
            [subject] => english 
            [svalue] => 2 [mvalue] => 2 
  ) 
  [2] => Array ( 
            [month] => mar 
            [subject] => physics 
            [svalue] => 3 
            [mvalue] => 3 
  ) 
)
```

so that my json string looks like

```
[ {"subjecttable":"subject","monthtable":"month","month":"jan","subject":"maths","svalue":"1","mvalue":"1"}, {"subjecttable":"svalue","monthtable":"mvalue","month":"feb","subject":"english","svalue":"2","mvalue":"2"}, {"month":"mar","subject":"physics","svalue":"3","mvalue":"3"} ]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Reading that makes my head hurt. Please edit. I bet it'll make the question more understandable, too.

Comment: don't think json_decode outputs what you gave us there based on your json :)

Comment: Ahhhhh.. that makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

without offense, the title is cryptic and the text seems to say the opposite

So if I understood correctly whay you need, simply do:

```
$new_array = array($your_array)
```

then you can convert it into Json format

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Shouldn't `json_encode($your_array)` get you the correct results already?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can use

```
print json_encode($array);
```

`json_encode()` function convert php object/array into javascript equivalent object.